# React/Flux implementation technique is unclear for when a parent component needs to pull strings on child component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have a situation which isn't too contrived, and I'm having trouble implementing it using the React best practices. In particular it produces this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setProps(...): You called `setProps` on a component with a parent. This is an anti-pattern since props will get reactively updated when rendered. Instead, change the owner's `render` method to pass the correct value as props to the component where it is created.

The situation is like this. The parent contains a child component. The parent has event handlers for UI and for the behavior to work, something inside the child component needs to render its HTML with a CSS change to the height style. Therein lies the wrinkle, usually the information flows upward or stays put, but here I need to change something in the child.

Parent component (`Widget`) renders this:

```
<div class="Widget">
  <div class="WidgetGrabBar" onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
  <WidgetDetails heightProp={this.props.detailsHeight} />
</div>
```

And elsewhere in Widget I've got

```
componentDidMount: function() { 
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp);
},
componentDidUnmount: function() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp);
},      

<...>

handleMouseDown: function(e) {                                                   
  e.preventDefault(); 
  this.props.actuallyDragging = true;                                                   
},
handleMouseUp: function(e) {
  this.props.actuallyDragging = false;
},       
handleMouseMove: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.props.actuallyDragging) {
    // update the prop! I need to send an urgent package of information to my child!! jQuery or findDOMElement() followed by DOM traversal is forbidden!!!
    this.setProps({
      detailsHeight: this.props.detailsHeight + e.deltaY
    });
  }                                                                                        
},
```

And I had `WidgetDetails`' `render()` render something like:

```
<div class="WidgetDetails" style={height: this.props.heightProp}>
   {detail_items_move_along_nothing_to_see_here}
</div>
```

I figured that rolling out the jQuery to grab `.WidgetDetails` to fiddle with its `style` attr is the *wrong* thing, the non-React way to go about it. The real anti-pattern.

But now I'm being told that I can't change my props. Or I have to throw out everything including the bathwater in order to have new props. I'm not doing that; my props contain the *contents* of the detail items. Maybe it is expensive to make another entirely new copy of this.

I'm trying to let React participate in this rendering work to put the new height in. How am I supposed to even do this? Is this error basically enforcing that Props are supposed to be immutable now? The error is telling me that I have to involve this height even farther up on the component chain. I can conceivably do so with a callback from up above, but this feels very wrong. I need to pass information downward, not upward.

Maybe I'm supposed to use `state`. But changing `state` forces `Widget`, the parent component to render. That is not what I desire. Only one singular place in the DOM needs to re-render, that is the *child* component's div's `style` attr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches. Either

1. call handlers on the parent. Then Pass the new props to the child via props. If I recall correctly, that's the approach the react hello world tutorial takes.
2. Mutate state in the view via setState.

In your case, it seems that approach 2 really makes sense. You are basically trying to track view data.

Never, by the way, update state directly. Use setState. The whole point of reacts virtual dom is that it's optimized for spurious updates, so you will be fine. There is also the life cycle method componentShouldUpdate in case you want finer control.

For completeness I should add that there's a third way of using a global store. That's what react flux adds. But again, in your case that's probably over kill.

Comment: OK so I take it you're saying to go with (2) because I am indicating that the parent (who is brought into the picture with option (1)) doesn't need to be bothered with this discardable state. Otherwise if suppose I wanted to persist the height that user dragged the bar to, I would use a callback to update it to a parent, that parent would update props to get the info to go back down into the child.

Comment: I do have a global event emitter. Do you mean for the third option to have WidgetDetails subscribe to an event and for the Widget to send events containing the height value as payload?

Comment: I can't help but feel like the 4th option (just use `findDOMNode` with a ref and step through to the child and mutate its style directly) is the cleanest...

Comment: No. Technically flux is a variation of option 1. Values flow from the store to the parent and then to child. In this case calculations would be done in store which doesn't make sense in this case

Comment: Option 4 will cause react to barf

Comment: I think option 4 causes exploding only if react has other duties updating the same attribute. Theres some older code around where a lot of dom style `display:none` was being changed and it continues to work great

Comment: It would also cause devs to explode for going jquery style. You asked what was the react style. It's not option 4 in your case

Comment: That's right! so it is certainly off the table. Now I'm just sort of puzzling over what you mean about the global store, but I think I'll build using (2) because I dont actually want to persist the height (but leaving it put until unmount is ideal)